# Should isset checks be done within a service that depends on a session being valid?

Tags: php, oop

I am working on a `UserSession` service, the code is below.

My question is, is there any need to do an `isset` test within the `get_id` method or should it be the responsibility of the calling code (in my case the controller) to ensure a session is active?

If the session isn't set, a failure would result in a logout, but I can't help but think that checking for the validity of a user session shouldn't be done in this service, as the use of this service requires a valid user session anyway.

I end up having to do this in every getter.

```
<?php

namespace \App\Services;

class UserSession {

    private $session;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->session = (object) $_SESSION;
    }

    public function get_id()
    {
        if(!isset($this->session->user->id))
            return false;

        return $this->session->user->id;
    }
}
```

Any advice?

I'm thinking maybe a method `is_valid()` that returns `true` or `false` is maybe needed. That way the use of the session can be checked prior to calling any of the getters.

Comment: I don't see any problem with it. It's a lot better to have it in the `get_id()` rather than in who knows how many places. Many PHP methods return *something* or false on failure. It's not uncommon. Take for example [`curl_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` set as an option. It will return either a string(on success) or false if it fails.

Comment: In my opinion, double check is always better. But if it isn't possible in any way to call this script if "$this->session->user->id" is not set. Then, yeah this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't avoid mixed return types. Most of the times it best practise to either return the expected result / type or throw an exception.

Second, you should fail as soon as possible. That means, as soon as you know that you'll need a UserSession to proceed, you should check if it's existing. That you either be in the class constructor, or even before trying to instantiate the UserSession object, e.g. by a factory or build pattern.

That class could although inject the content of the `$_SESSION` Superglobal to the UserSession to remove the class dependency and make it testable easier.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in the end. Good point on injecting the `$_SESSION` too.

Answer (score 0):

You should add user session check in `__construct` that way if you have 50 methods checking for valid session occurs only once and other methods does not need to repeat code.

And yes, always check if user session exists before trying to use it (you never know what may happen that leads to empty user session).

Comment: I'm struggling to see how I would handle an error at the time of instantiation (I use `Pimple`). And if it fails at construction I couldn't really handle the error within the container. I could handle it more precisely at the controller level because I'd likely need to log the request that caused the error as it's unlikely in the application for the UserSession to never be set.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Simply throw error if condition is not met.